# Integrate Jekyll to run into WebStorm on Windows

Tags: windows, jekyll, webstorm

Is it possible to run Jekyll as External Tool into WebStorm? (same for RubyMine, IntelliJ IDEA, ...)

The most obvious thing is to run the `jekyll.bat` file:

[image]

...but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found any solution so after some trial+error I discover this working configuration:

[image]

In this example I am using: [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) + `gem install jekyll`.

If you prefer using *straight* Ruby+DevKit then `Program` and `Parameters` paths must be changed according.

Comment: It works great! Thanks Filippo. I left parameters only to `jekyll server --watch` but it did't work so I had to set the full path to jekyll in ruby.